# Not getting second Fetch

Tags: php

Hey everyone I have been trying to figure this out for a while and just cant get around while its not showing the second fetch where weaponF is,

```
     <?php 
session_start(); 
if(!$_SESSION['logged']){ 
    header("Location: login_page.php"); 
    exit; 
}  





?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<style type="text/css">
div {
position: relative;
left: 5px;
top: 25px;
width: 280px;
padding: 10px;
color: black;
display: none;
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id1,id2,id3) {
if(document.getElementById('bt1').value=='H'){
document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'S';
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'none';
}else{
document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'H';
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'inline';
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'inline';
document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'inline';
}
}

function setvisibility(id4){
    if(document.getElementById('bt2').value=='HP'){
        document.getElementById('bt2').value = 'SP';
        document.getElementById('id4').style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('bt2').value = 'HP';
        document.getElementById('id4').style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

function setvisibility(id5){
    if(document.getElementById('bt3').value=='HC'){
        document.getElementById('bt3').value = 'SC';
        document.getElementById('id5').style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('bt3').value = 'HC';
        document.getElementById('id5').style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

function setvisibility(id6){
    if(document.getElementById('bt4').value=='HM'){
        document.getElementById('bt4').value = 'SM';
        document.getElementById('id6').style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('bt4').value = 'HM';
        document.getElementById('id6').style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

function setvisibility(id7){
    if(document.getElementById('bt5').value=='HI'){
        document.getElementById('bt5').value = 'SI';
        document.getElementById('id7').style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('bt5').value = 'HI';
        document.getElementById('id7').style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
</script>


<body>
<center>
<?php


 $con=mysqli_connect(secret);
$validUser = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['username']);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT level, exp, maxexp, str, dex, inte, sta, crit, hp, atk, def, dfire, dwater, dposion, atkfire, atkwater, atkposion, weapon FROM users WHERE username = '$validUser'");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$weapon = $data['weapon'];
$weaponQ = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE wname= '$weapon'") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
$weaponF = mysqli_fetch_array($weaponQ,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<body><center>
<table border="1">
<td>Level:<?php echo $data['level']; ?></td>
<td
<?php if ($data['exp'] == $data['maxexp']) {
    echo "bgcolor = white";
}
else
{
    echo "bgcolor = white";
}
     ?>
>Exp:<?php echo $data['exp']; ?>/<?php echo $data['maxexp']; ?></td>
<td>Str:<?php echo $data['str']; ?></td>
<td>Dex:<?php echo $data['dex']; ?></td>
<td>Int:<?php echo $data['inte']; ?></td>
<td>Stam:<?php echo $data['sta']; ?></td>
<td>Crit:<?php echo $data['crit']; ?>%</td>
</table>

<?php
if ($data['exp'] == $data['maxexp']) {
    echo "<a href='levelup.php'>Level up </a>";
    }
else
{
    echo "";
}
?>

</center>
<table border="1" align="left">
<tr>
<td>
<a onclick="setVisibility('sub3','sub4','sub5');" id="bt1" href="#">Explore</a><br /><br />
<a onclick="setVisibility('sub6');" id="bt4" href="#">Market</a><br /><br />
<a onclick="setVisibility('sub1');" id="bt2" href="#">Profile</a><br /><br />
<a onclick="setVisibility('sub2');" id="bt3" href="#">Casino</a><br /><br />
<a onclick="setVisibility('sub7');" id="bt5" href="#">Inventory</a><br /><br />
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br />
<div id="sub3" align="center">Map</div>

<br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="sub4" align="center">Arrows</div>
 <div id="sub5" align="center">Mobs</div>
 <div id="sub1" align="center">
 <table border="1" align="center">
 <td>
 <?php
 echo "<font size='+2'>Base Stats</font>";
 echo "<br><br>";
 echo "Str: ";
 echo $data['str'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Dex: ";
 echo $data['dex'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Int: ";
 echo $data['inte'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Stam: ";
 echo $data['sta'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Crit: ";
 echo $data['crit'];
 echo "%";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Atk: ";
 echo $data['atk'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Def: ";
 echo $data['def'];
 echo "<br><br>";
 echo "<font size='+2'>Bonus Atk</font>";
 echo "<br><br>";
 echo "Atk Fire: ";
 echo $data['atkfire'];
 echo "%";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Atk Water: ";
 echo $data['atkwater'];
 echo "%";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Atk Posion: ";
 echo $data['atkposion'];
 echo "%";
 echo "<br><br>";
 echo "<font size='+2'>Bonus Res</font>";
 echo "<br><br>";
 echo "Def Fire: ";
 echo $data['dfire'];
 echo "%";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Def Water: ";
 echo $data['dwater'];
 echo "%";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "Def Posion: ";
 echo $data['dposion'];
 echo "%";
 ?>
 </td>

 </table>
 </div>
 <div id="sub2" align="center">Casino</div>
 <div id="sub6" align="center">Market</div>
 <div id="sub7" align="center">
 <table border="1" bordercolor="white">
 <tr>
 <td bordercolor="white" height="50px" width="50px"></td>
  <td width="50px" height="50px" bordercolor="black">
 Head
 </td>
 </tr><br />
 <tr>
 <td width="50px" height="50px" bordercolor="black">

<img onmouseover="<?php echo $weaponF['name']; ?>" src="equipment/<?php echo $data['weapon']; ?>.png" />
 </td>
 <td width="50px" height="50px" bordercolor="black">
 Chest
 </td>
 <td width="50px" height="50px" bordercolor="black">
 RightArm
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td bordercolor="white" height="50px" width="50px">
 </td>
 <td bordercolor="black" height="50px" width="50px">
 Pants
 </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td bordercolor="white" height="50px" width="50px">
</td>
 <td bordercolor="black" height="50px" width="50px">
 Shoes
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
<?php echo $data['weapon'];
        echo $weaponF['wname']; ?>
</body>
```

It dose not show any errors or faults, Please help haha here is all my code make it easier to view and help I hope lol

Comment: `'$validUser'=username` should be `username = '$validUser'` ?

Comment: nope its working good, im having an issue with the $weaponF not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think `username` and `name` is your table columns so try

```
$validUser = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['username']);
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$validUser' LIMIT 1");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT level, exp, maxexp, str, dex, inte, sta, crit, hp, atk, def, dfire, dwater, dposion, atkfire, atkwater, atkposion, weapon FROM users WHERE username = '$validUser'");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$weapon = $data['weapon'];
$weaponQ = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE wname= '$weapon'") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($weaponQ) > 0) {
  $weaponF = mysqli_fetch_array($weaponQ,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
else {
  echo 'No rows found';
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

and also there is no work of below query so you can remove this:-

```
 mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$validUser' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: then you need to check $validuser exist or your query is ok

Comment: Saw that and removed it haha, but looking over it and its still not showing any errors or any problems or the data lol

Comment: everything works But the $weaponF that is the only one not working

Comment: just changed name= '$weapon' to wname= '$weapon' still dident work was just making sure there was no confusion between username and name

Comment: check echo $weapon = $data['weapon']; and run query and make sure you are using correct field name

Comment: echo $data['weapon'];
  echo $weaponF['wname']

So $data Works fine but
$weaponF dose not work...

Comment: Just edited and showed all my code I hope that helps because I am stumped lol ill keep looking over and over but im lost.

Comment: echo "SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE wname= '$weapon'"; and run your query in phpmyadmin if any result coming?

Comment: OMFG thank you, I am a complete MORON forgot to add sw2 to equipment list only had sw1 wow I am so sorry for wasting your time on my stupid mistake. database screw up :(